# how to report p-values from t-test and ks test in the same table for publication?

Tags: p-value, tables

I want to show in a table that two samples are different in a number of attributes (or not different). 
I want to report the mean, st.err. and the stars at conventional values of p-value from a t-test showing that the mean is different. However, for some attributes I also want to show the p-value from a Kolmogorov/Smirnov test on the same table. How to do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: What about adding a column for each p-value? One for p-values from the t-test and one with p-values from KS?

Comment: Mightn't the approach to presenting such a table rather depend on the journal's editorial approach? The first step would be to check for somewhat similar tables in other papers.

Comment: Yes, It does depend on the publication. And maybe I should go with the two columns of p-value. However for many attributes it seems to me to overload the reader with too much information. I was hoping for some sort of convention used by someone (but I also understand that conventions differ across fields)